# Type "opaque" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I have an assigment where I have to execuse this PostagreSQLat my PgAdmin interface.
Query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "f_1"() RETURNS "opaque" AS '
DECLARE
    v_laiks timestamp;
    v_liet varchar;
BEGIN
    v_laiks := now();
    v_liet := current_user;
    RAISE NOTICE ''=== Sakums ==='';
    RAISE NOTICE ''Laiks - %'', v_laiks;
    RAISE NOTICE ''Lietotajs - %'', v_liet;
    RAISE NOTICE ''Operacija -%'', TG_OP;
    IF (TG_OP = ''DELETE'' OR TG_OP = ''UPDATE'') THEN
        RAISE NOTICE '' Vec_vert - %'', old.marka;
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = ''INSERT'' OR TG_OP = ''UPDATE'') THEN
        RAISE NOTICE '' Jaun_vert - %'', new.marka;
    END IF;
    RAISE NOTICE ''Parametrs - %'',TG_ARGV[0];
    RAISE NOTICE ''=== Beigas ==='';
    RETURN NEW;
END;' 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And I get:

*ERROR:  type "opaque" does not exist
SQL state: 42704*

Can't find why it wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `opaque` data type has long been obsolete and has been removed in commit [bb03010b9f0](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=bb03010b9f0766e10399174fe850b2506907c4e4) in PostgreSQL v13.

Use `RETURNS trigger` for trigger functions.